# Make element hover when unhovering, add close button so it remembers cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I am trying to make a tooltip, but I need it to stay hovering when user unhovers.

Also, I am trying to add a close button to that tooltip, that will stay with the "hover state" and when user clicks on it, I want to make it to remember cookies so it will not open again for that cookie.

I am a novice at javascript and jQuery and have been breaking my mind on this for several days now.

Here is my code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* Tooltip CSS Created By Deni*/

.tooltip-container {
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 background: #DBDBDB;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 10% auto;
}

/* Start the tooltip css */

.tooltip {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 9998;
 cursor: help;
}
.tooltip > span {
 display: none;
}
.tooltip:hover {
 z-index:  9999;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltip-data {
 display: block;
 width: 150px;
 padding: 5px;
 color: #dadada;
 background-color: #A35FA1;
 font-size: 11px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: century gothic;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 20px;
 left: -10px;
 text-align: center;
}
.tooltip-container > a {
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.permhover {
 display: block;
 opacity: 1;
}
**HTML:**
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tooltip</title>
<link href="tooltip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <div class="tooltip-container">
     <a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip">This is the information<span class="tooltip-data"> This is one Tooltip!</span></a>   
     <a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip">This is the information <span class="tooltip-data"> This another one Tooltip!</span></a>   
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I know that is not much but all the help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to change all lines in css from ".tooltip:hover"  to ".tooltip.hover".
Next you need to add `<button class="btn-close"></button>`  to your tooltip (this button will close this tooltip)

Then you need to add jquery code, that will add class hover to tooltip when you hover it.

```
(function(){
    $('.tooltip').each(function(){
        var tooltip = $(this);
        var tooltipId = tooltip.attr('id');

        if( !getCookie(tooltipId) ) {
            tooltip.on('mouseenter.tooltip', function(){
                tooltip.addClass('hover');

                tooltip.find('.btn-close').on('click', function(){
                    var date = new Date();
                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

                    tooltip.removeClass('hover').off('mouseenter.tooltip');

                    document.cookie = tooltipId + "=true; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
                });
            });
        }
    });

    function getCookie(name) {
        var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
        return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to make when a user clicks on the tooltip that it never shows again, so I was thinking the best way would be with cookies.

Comment: I edited my variant and added cookies parameter. But you need to add an ID attribute to each tooltip

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I try this code it is not working. Could you please elaborate more this solution?

Comment: Could you screen your code editor with code? I'll check it for mistakes

Comment: I have just check code and everything works fine. Please ensure that you added id-attribute to each tooltip

Comment: I'm probably making a mistake somewhere. Could you give me an example please?

Comment: Amazing job!! Wow, just wow, I wasn't adding the id's so I'm to blame.

Comment: By the way I know I have already thanked you, but one more thing please:
How can I make that entire div disappear, not only the hovered part?

Comment: Hi, If the question is still actual: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/I9zbm8NEjD7rVqNuKRgX?p=preview

Comment: One more, sorry: For some reason this is not working in Chrome... Could you let me know why please?

Comment: I think, you tried to do it locally? Chrome doesn't support cookie for local pages. You should use some server

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks. Didn't know that Chrome doesn't support local. Mozilla does. Thanks. :)

Comment: Denys, please see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988053/how-to-make-two-tooltip-ids-independently-close-and-remember-cookie

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution of this would be to register the onmouseout event on the links and display your tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a x by adding a `span` to the `.tooltip-data`.
Then use jQuery to active the tooltip on mousehover and remove it by a click on the x span.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.tooltip').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find('span').show().append('');
  });
  $('.tooltip-data span').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* Tooltip CSS Created By Deni*/

.tooltip-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #DBDBDB;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10% auto;
}
/* Start the tooltip css */

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9998;
  cursor: help;
}
.tooltip > span {
  display: none;
}
.tooltip:hover {
  z-index: 9999;
}
.tooltip-data {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #dadada;
  background-color: #A35FA1;
  font-size: 11px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: century gothic;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: -10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.tooltip-data span {
  float: right;
}
.tooltip-container > a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.permhover {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip-container">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip">
      This is the information
      <span class="tooltip-data"> This is one Tooltip! <span> x </span></span>
    </a> 
  <a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip">
      This is the information 
      <span class="tooltip-data"> This another one Tooltip!<span> x </span></span>
    </a> 
</div>
```