# How to make two tooltip ids independently close, and remember cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I'm trying to make a tooltip using jQuery, with HTML and CSS. 
Each tooltip is different by the id and that works great, so I can make as many tooltips as I want and style them independently.

What I lack to understand is how can I make a tooltip to close, without affecting other tooltip(s). I'm using Regex Exp for cookies and all tooltips are on the same page.

Please note that `#tooltip2` appears several time (4) on different locations on website, while `#tooltip1` appears only once. If I click close on `#tooltip2` I don't want it to affect `#tooltip1`, but to close all `#tooltip2` divs. 
If I click close on `#tooltip1`, I want it only to close `#tooltip1` divs.

Here is a part of code:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltipMe no-print" id="tooltip1"><img src="images/icons/icon-tooltip-help.png" /><span class="tooltip-data">Tooltip 1 Text<span class="outerone"><span class="btn-close"><img src="http:/images/icons/icon-tooltip-close.png"  /></span></span></span></a></span>

<span class="tooltip-master"><a href="javascript:;" class="tooltipMe no-print" id="tooltip2"><img src="/images/icons/icon-tooltip-help.png" /><span class="tooltip-data">Tooltip 2 Text<span class="outer"><span class="btn-close"><img src="images/icons/icon-tooltip-close.png"  /></span></span></span></a>
```

jQuery

```
(function(){
    $('.tooltipMe').each(function(){
        var tooltip = $(this);
        var tooltipId = tooltip.attr('id');

        if( !getCookie(tooltipId) ) {
            tooltip.on('click.tooltipMe', function(){
                tooltip.addClass('hover');

                tooltip.find('.btn-close').on('click', function(){
                    var date = new Date();
                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                  //tooltip.removeClass('hover').off('mouseenter.tooltip'); - in case we want to remove only tooltip
                  // Start of #tooltip1
                    $('.outerone > .btn-close').each(function(){ //code for #tooltip 1 - using 'each'
                        $('.tooltip-masterone > .tooltipMe').hide('fast'); //select what to hide and how
                    document.cookie = tooltipId + "=true; path=/; expires=Th, 31 Dec 2099 11:00:00 GMT;" + date.toUTCString();

                     function getCookie(name) {
        var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
        return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined; // cookie solution with RegExp
    }
                    });
                  // #tooltip1 end line
                  // Start of #tooltip2
                    $('.outer > .btn-close').on('click', function(){ //code for #tooltip 2 - using 'click'
                        $('.tooltip-master > .tooltipMe').hide('fast'); //select what to hide and how

                    document.cookie = tooltipId + "=true; path=/; expires=Th, 31 Dec 2099 11:00:00 GMT;" + date.toUTCString();

                    });
                });
            });
        }
        else {
          tooltip.hide();
        }
    });

    function getCookie(name) {
        var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
        return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined; // cookie solution with RegExp
    }})();
```

How can I make the tooltips close independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out the answer to this, and I'm posting only as I want to contribute to this community. This maybe not very common request, but I am sure some will stumble on it and I will be more than happy knowing that it actually helped someone.

```
(function(){
$('.tooltipMe').each(function(){
    var tooltip = $(this);
    var tooltipId = tooltip.attr('id');

    if( !getCookie(tooltipId) ) {
        tooltip.on('click.tooltipMe', function(){
            tooltip.addClass('hover');

            tooltip.find('.close-one > .btn-close').on('click', function(){ //accuratelly target .btn-close class
                var date = new Date();
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
              //tooltip.removeClass('hover').off('mouseenter.tooltip'); - in case we want to remove only tooltip
              // Start of #tooltip1
                $('.close-one > .btn-close').each(function(){ //code for #tooltip 1 - using 'each'
                    $('.tooltip-masterone > #tooltip1').fadeOut('slow'); //select what to hide and how      

                document.cookie = tooltipId + "=true; path=/; expires=Th, 31 Dec 2099 11:00:00 GMT;" + date.toUTCString();  
                });
            });
              // #tooltip1 end line

              // Start of #tooltip2
               tooltip.find('.close-two > .btn-close').on('click', function(){ //accuratelly target .btn-close class
                var date = new Date();
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                $('.close-two > .btn-close').each(function(){ //code for #tooltip 2 - using 'each'
                    $('.tooltip-master > #tooltip2').fadeOut('slow'); //select what to hide and how

                document.cookie = tooltipId + "=true; path=/; expires=Th, 31 Dec 2099 11:00:00 GMT;" + date.toUTCString();

                });
            });
            // tooltip2 end line
        });
    }
    else {
      tooltip.hide();
    }
});

function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined; // cookie solution with RegExp
}
```

So the solution is pretty simple: **you need to target each class more "precise", so it will not close ".btn-close" generally, like it did before, but it will close the exact ".btn-close" inside the parent class.** ie.

```
$('.class > .class.').each(function(){});
```

Now each #tooltip is closed independently and you can put as many tooltips as you want. I'm sure there are better solutions to this, like placing a variable for each ".class > .class", but this works great as well.

Cheers.