# How to make two IDs remember cookie and independently close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I've tried this on many places, but not here.

I'm trying to make a tooltip using jQuery, with HTML and CSS. Each tooltip is different by the id and that works great, so I can make as many tooltips as I want and style them independently.

What I lack to understand is how can I make a tooltip to close, without affecting other tooltip(s). I'm using Regex Exp for cookies and all tooltips are on the same page.

Please note that `#tooltip2` appears several time (4) on different locations on website, while `#tooltip1` appears only once. If I click close on `#tooltip2` I don't want it to affect `#tooltip1`, but to close all `#tooltip2` divs. If I click close on `#tooltip1`, I want it only to close #tooltip1 divs.

Here is a part of code:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltipMe no-print" id="tooltip1"><img src="images/icons/icon-tooltip-help.png" /><span class="tooltip-data">Tooltip 1 Text<span class="outerone"><span class="btn-close"><img src="http:/images/icons/icon-tooltip-close.png"  /></span></span></span></a></span>

 <span class="tooltip-master"><a href="javascript:;" class="tooltipMe no-print" id="tooltip2"><img src="/images/icons/icon-tooltip-help.png" /><span class="tooltip-data">Tooltip 2 Text<span class="outer"><span class="btn-close"><img src="images/icons/icon-tooltip-close.png"  /></span></span></span></a>
```

jQuery

```
(function(){
$('.tooltipMe').each(function(){
    var tooltip = $(this);
    var tooltipId = tooltip.attr('id');

    if( !getCookie(tooltipId) ) {
        tooltip.on('click.tooltipMe', function(){
            tooltip.addClass('hover');

            tooltip.find('.btn-close').on('click', function(){
                var date = new Date();
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
              //tooltip.removeClass('hover').off('mouseenter.tooltip'); - in case we want to remove only tooltip
              // Start of #tooltip1
                $('.outerone > .btn-close').each(function(){ //code for #tooltip 1 - using 'each'
                    $('.tooltip-masterone > .tooltipMe').hide('fast'); //select what to hide and how
                document.cookie = tooltipId + "=true; path=/; expires=Th, 31 Dec 2099 11:00:00 GMT;" + date.toUTCString();

                 function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined; // cookie solution with RegExp
}
                });
              // #tooltip1 end line
              // Start of #tooltip2
                $('.outer > .btn-close').on('click', function(){ //code for #tooltip 2 - using 'click'
                    $('.tooltip-master > .tooltipMe').hide('fast'); //select what to hide and how

                document.cookie = tooltipId + "=true; path=/; expires=Th, 31 Dec 2099 11:00:00 GMT;" + date.toUTCString();

                });
            });
        });
    }
    else {
      tooltip.hide();
    }
});

function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined; // cookie solution with RegExp
}})();
```

This all works perfectly, but I don't know how to close this independently. Tooltip2 closes tooltip1, then it closes afterwards, while tooltip1 works okay if clicked first.

Comment: Are you aware that there is a global HTML attribute called 'title' which can be used to display tooltips?

Comment: Why is getCookie(name) defined twice?

Comment: I was thinking that each time I need to fetch "cookie"

Comment: Note that it is invalid to have more than one element in a document with the same id.  Use classes to classify elements, not id.

Comment: Thanks dsh.. could you please show me the solution on this code, I'm not that experienced with jQuery?

Comment: This question is an identical repost of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31988053/1172714